# The second Ionisation energy of the Zn, Cd, and Hg follows the order?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, ionization-energy

It is observed that the order of second ionisation energy of these three elements is $\ce{Zn > Cd < Hg}$.

Why is there an anomaly in the observation?

Comment: Do you know *which* of the three is anomalous?

Comment: @orthocresol yes, the ionization energy should decrease down the group: Zn>Cd>Hg. The behavior of Hg is anomalous.

Comment: Excellent. The answer has to do with relativistic stabilisation of the 6s orbital. Probably you will find more material on Stack Exchange, or on the wider Internet, or in a textbook.

Comment: @orthocresol It's not in my high school textbook, I'm not familiar with the relativistic stabilisation. I looked it up and found that 6s electrons experience an inward force due to the increment in mass of $e^-$ for moving at a higher speed. Is it correct?

Comment: Some authors also claim that the electrons in the f-orbitals do not shield the nuclear charge as well as electrons in other orbitals.

Answer (score 3):

In the lower part of the periodic table, the nucleus charge becomes so high that the electron must rotate at a relativist speed to stay in orbit in the Bohr's model. And even if the Bohr's model is outdated, it can be used to explain the strange chemistry happening in the heaviest atoms.

Relativity says that when an object moves at a speed not far from *c*, its dimension decreases. That is the case for electrons in the heaviest atoms. And this effect is proportional to the sum of the quantum numbers *n* and *l*. Mercury's configuration for example is $(Xe) 4f^{14} 5d^{10} 6s^2$. The corresponding quantum numbers *n* and *l* give successively *n+l* = 4+4, 5+3, 6+1. So for these electrons, *n+l* is 8 or 7. This is huge. Their orbital dimensions are so heavily contracted that they disappeared inside the inner orbitals, where *n+l* is not so high. As a consequence, the mercury atom looks like the xenon atom when observed from outside. And indeed it is "nearly a noble gas", as its boiling temperature is so much lower than its neighbors in the table, like gold (Au) or hallium (Tl). This is also why the ionization potential is so high: mercury behaves nearly like a noble gas.

All this theory is discussed in great detail in Pyykkö Pekka's articles, like
- P. Pekka, Relativist Effects in Structural Chemistry, Chemical Review 88, 3, 563 - 594 (1988)
- P. Pekka, Relativity and the Periodic System of Elements, Accounts of Chemical Research 12. 8, 271 - 276 (1979).
 A short summary can be found in Wikipedia, under the title "Relativist quantum chemistry".

This relativistic effect explains also why mercury's neighbors behave like xenon neighbors. On the right-hand side of $\ce{Hg}$, thallium ($\ce{Tl}$) is a near alkali-metal atom, as it may have +1 as an oxidation number. On its left-hand side. Gold is nearly a halogen, as it may form an anion $\ce{Au-}$ in the cubic crystal of "caesium auride" $\ce{CsAu}$. Further on the right-hand side, lead shows some similarities to barium, assuming a +2 oxidation state and having its sulfate $\ce{PbSO4}$ relatively insoluble in water like $\ce{BaSO4}$.